# Simplify the expression below by using the Algebra laws:

Tags: boolean-algebra

Simplify the expression below by using the Algebra laws:
$$ AB + \overline{(\bar AC + B)\cdot \overline{(\bar B \oplus C)}} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ AB + \overline{(\bar AC + B)\cdot \overline{(\bar B \oplus C)}} $$
$$ \text{Demorgan} $$
$$ AB + (\overline{\overline AC + B}) + (\overline B \oplus C)$$
$$ \text{Demorgan} $$
$$ AB + \overline{\overline A C}\overline B + (\overline B \oplus C)$$
$$ \text{Demorgan sure is busy today} $$
$$ AB + (A + \overline C)\overline B + (\overline B \oplus C)$$
$$ \text {Distribute} $$
$$ AB + A \overline B + \overline C \overline B + (\overline B \oplus C)$$
$$ \text {expand xor} $$
$$ AB + A \overline B + \overline C \overline B + BC + \overline B \overline C$$
$$ \text {simplify A + A} $$
$$ AB + A \overline B + BC + \overline B \overline C$$
$$ \text {undistribute, xnor} $$
$$ A(B + \overline B) + B \overline \oplus C$$
$$ \text {simplify vacuous or} $$
$$ A + B \overline \oplus C$$
$$ \text {copy paste post into homework and hope teacher doesn't catch you}$$